# Is it possible to provide multiple roles in aws credentials provider using STS in spring boot?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services

Currently I have three roles, wherein each has the separate SQS access. I am connecting to AWS by using the roles.
For connecting with single role, this code is helpful.

```
@Value("${cloud.aws.assumeRoleARN:}")
private String assumeRoleARN;

@Autowired
private AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider;

@Bean
@Primary
public AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {
    log.info("Assuming role {}",assumeRoleARN);
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(assumeRoleARN)) {
        AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration())
                .withRegion("us-east-1")
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .build();

        return new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider
                .Builder(assumeRoleARN, "test")
                .withStsClient(stsClient)
                .build();
    }
   return awsCredentialsProvider;
}
```

But I need same credentials for all the three roles which I have. Is it possible to pass list of regions in the AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder?

Thanks in Advance!